# Azure CosmosDB Stored Procedure: set custom id for document

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the upsert method to create / update a document (https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/Collection.html#upsertDocument). I would like to use another field that has not the name "id" as id for the document but can't find an option to do so in this method.

Can I set a custom id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a custom field with another name as "id" is not possible. Either you have a field with the name "id" in the document you upsert or a id with a guid is generated (if the document has to be created).

So what is necessary to do is to create a field (if not available) with the name "id" in the document you want to upsert and set it to the value from the field you want to have as id.